# jQuery checkbox not displaying correctly when included in SlickGrid

Tags: jquery, slickgrid

I am trying to display a jquery checkbox on my page but having some trouble.  When I display the checkbox inside a [SlickGrid](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid) it displays as a regular checkbox, not jQuery style.  When I display a checkbox in other areas of the page (not in the SlickGrid), it displays correctly in the jQuery style, so I must have the correct libraries referenced.

Here is the code that displays a checkbox in the grid:

```
var propertiesTitleFormatter = function(row, cell, value, columnDef, dataContext) {
return  "#"+eval(row+1)+"<input type='checkbox' id='sale_check' onclick='UpdateSelected()' class='s_box' name='s_maybe'>"+" "+monthNames[Number(dataContext["saleMonth"].slice(-2))]  + ", " + dataContext["saleMonth"].slice(0,4)+"<br>"+toTitleCase(dataContext["address"])+", "+dataContext["municipality"];
};

var columns = [
{id:"address", name:"Address", field:"address",width:175,resizable:false,formatter:propertiesTitleFormatter, cssClass:"cell-properties"},
];
```

Is there anything that I am doing wrong here?  Why does this checkbox not display correctly when it is part of the data grid?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set a css class inside a custom formatter. See a pull request that I submitted for this, and mliebman commented that formatters should not be modifying the column definition. Use getItemMetaData instead.

https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/pull/598

Edit: To be honest, I never figured out how to use getItemMetaData(). I had modified the slickgrid code for my project "temporarily" until I figured it out, and it stuck.

Comment: Thanks for offering your suggestion.  Did you manage to get it working eventually?

Comment: I ended up using the modified slick.grid.js (like in the pull request above) - Once you have that in, you can modify the columnDef.cssClass property inside your custom formatter, which will apply it to your div. Applying to your checkbox would be similar i hope.

Comment: Thanks again.  Where would I find the modified slick.grid.js ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that SlickGrid will add the checkbox dynamically after the jQuery UI markup magic has been done. In order to markup the checkbox manually you will have to call

```
$(function() {
    $( "#sale_check" ).button();
});
```

Try

```
var propertiesTitleFormatter = function(row, cell, value, columnDef, dataContext) {
return  "#"+eval(row+1)+"<input type='checkbox' id='sale_check' onclick='UpdateSelected()' class='s_box' name='s_maybe'>"+" "+monthNames[Number(dataContext["saleMonth"].slice(-2))]  + ", " + dataContext["saleMonth"].slice(0,4)+"<br>"+toTitleCase(dataContext["address"])+", "+dataContext["municipality"] + ' <script>$(function() {$( "#sale_check" ).button();})();</script>';
};
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are suggesting me to try.  The `propertiesTitleFormatter` is the same as the original that I posted.  I am also not clear on how to markup the checkbox manually.  When exactly would I call that function?

Comment: That formatter i entered had a javascript tag at the end that would do the manual markup for you. The javascript would have to be executed once the input had been added to the DOM. That means you would have to call it after the formatter had run but before the formatter closes.

Comment: Thanks @DGS.  I eventually noticed the javascript tag at the end of the formatter that you entered, but when I tried to use it, I got an error.  I can't seem to get the syntax correct.